# I use ToolBar in my app and I want to custom the width of menu but I do not how to do?

Tags: android, toolbar

I want to change the width of menu with ToolBar .Here is my code.but it not working

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">11dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">70dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHeight">190dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the width of the menu? hamburger icon?